# Xenomai on Ubuntu: vxworks skin disabled?

Tags: ubuntu, vxworks, xenomai

i am new to Xenomai so please forgive me if my question is silly

i have installed xenomai 2.4.8 in my ubuntu 11.04 with the command

```
apt-get install libxenomai-dev
```

Now i want test a simple vxWorks program, but when i compile my program, i receive this message

```
Xenomai: vxworksskin or CONFIG_XENO_OPT_PERVASIVE disabled
(modprobe xeno_vxworks?)
```

and output of modprobe xeno_vxworks is

```
FATAL: Module xeno_vxworks not found
```

My question is, how can i eanble xeno_vxworks module ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Xenomai, but it sounds like you need to download the source and `make` it yourself instead of installing from the Ubuntu repository.

Then, when configuring the package, there should be an option to build it or not, as the source directories suggest (http://svn.gna.org/svn/xenomai/trunk/src/skins/)